# Android Google map v3 - Limit specific area

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there any way to prevent user scroll pass a specific area using Google map?
I added a ground overlay on the map, and I don't want user scroll pass it. I found https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restrict-panning but user still can see a little map around the overlay (see image below). Any suggestions will be appreciated.
[image]

My code:

```
   @Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap mMap) {
    final LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(10.762657076386494, 106.65704530350968), new LatLng(10.783062032257044, 106.67223733537003));
    mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.images))
            .positionFromBounds(bounds));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.getCenter(), 18));
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds);

}
```

Comment: There could be zoom behavior issues at the boundaries which maps doesn't support.

Comment: I think it's because of the tile of map, the map will alway draw a whole tile, so there's a padding around the groundOverlay

Comment: I upvoted you, but I would suggest thinking about what needs to happen at the listener level.  E.g. if a drag right would reveal a left bounds past what you want to allow, that action needs to be blocked.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that way, and try to implement it, thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576307/6117565